# Apache CXF JaxWsProxyFactoryBean SSL Configuration call to external https fails

Tags: spring, docker, ssl, cxf, keytool

I have a spring microservice docker deployed.
I use JaxWsProxyFactoryBean to call an external server (soap/wsdl) and all goes well using http://externalServer:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean jaxWsProxyFactoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setAddress("http://externalServer");
...
```

The problem raise on when I call https in setAddress.

I registered the key/certificate, of the called server, in keystore using keytool and saving to /root/.keystore (the standard) importing it from pfx.
When I try to call the https I obtain this error:

```
org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLUtils  : Default key managers cannot be initialized: Password must not be null
```

Ok, I'm missing a password. But where put this maleficent password? In the application.yml? In system property? [The password used in keystore is the standard (changeit)]

EDITED

Here a snapshot of the log:

```
DEBUG 1 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLUtils  : The location of the key store has not been set via a system parameter or through configuration so the default value of /root/.keystore will be used.
DEBUG 1 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLUtils  : The key store password has not been set via a system property or through configuration, reading data from the keystore will fail.
DEBUG 1 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLUtils  : The key password has not been set via a system property or through configuration, reading data from the keystore will fail.
DEBUG 1 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLUtils  : The keystore type has not been set in configuration so the default value of JKS will be used.
WARN 1 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLUtils  : Default key managers cannot be initialized: Password must not be null
```

Standard keystore is used but with no password.

Comment: How did you configured SSL configuration for your Apache CXF client? Can you share an example please?

Comment: I use springboot to run all, with no particular configuration. Where I find this config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at our conversation under the comment section from your question I can conclude that your Apache CXF does not have ssl configured. What you need to do is read your keystore containing the trusted certificates and load it into your `SSLContext` with the TrustManagerFactory and TrustManager.

Below is an example configuration which you can try out:

**Option 1 - Plain Java**

```java
import org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusFactory;
import org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduitConfigurer;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.KeyStore;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream identityAsInputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("/path/to/your/identity.jks"));
        KeyStore identity = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        identity.load(identityAsInputStream, "keystore-password".toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(identity, "key-password".toCharArray());
        KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

        InputStream trustStoreInputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("/path/to/your/truststore.jks"));
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(trustStoreInputStream, "truststore-password".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);

        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setAddress("https://some-secure-server.com/");

        factory.setBus(new CXFBusFactory().createBus());
        factory.getBus().setExtension((name, address, httpConduit) -> {
            TLSClientParameters tls = new TLSClientParameters();
            tls.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tls);
        }, HTTPConduitConfigurer.class);

        WebClient webClient = factory.createWebClient();
    }
}
```

**Option 2 - Simplified configuration with library**

```java
import nl.altindag.ssl.SSLFactory;
import org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusFactory;
import org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduitConfigurer;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SSLFactory sslFactory = SSLFactory.builder()
                .withIdentityMaterial(Paths.get("/path/to/your/identity.jks"), "keystore-password".toCharArray())
                .withTrustMaterial(Paths.get("/path/to/your/truststore.jks"), "truststore-password".toCharArray())
                .build();

        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setAddress("https://some-secure-server.com/");

        factory.setBus(new CXFBusFactory().createBus());
        factory.getBus().setExtension((name, address, httpConduit) -> {
            TLSClientParameters tls = new TLSClientParameters();
            tls.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory.getSslSocketFactory());
            httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tls);
        }, HTTPConduitConfigurer.class);

        WebClient webClient = factory.createWebClient();
    }
}
```

The library is available here: [GitHub - SSLContext Kickstart](https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart)

I also have here a working example of the cxf client for one-way and two-way authentication based on ssl: [GitHub - Example Apache CXF client ssl configuration](https://github.com/Hakky54/mutual-tls-ssl/blob/e14dbb5a69dcca6419a3b1949ed021903c0f3a8b/client/src/main/java/nl/altindag/client/ClientConfig.java#L191)

Comment: Thanks @Hakan54 I have JaxWsProxyFactoryBean and not JAXRSClientFactoryBean. (My call goes to a webserver) From log message I see a keystore is loaded (the standard /root/.keystore) but the password is null. My problem is how to pass this password (and eventually a different location for the keystore).

Comment: Ah, I have overseen that. My bad. I have adjusted my code snippet with additional example for loading the keystore from a different path and also the custom password option. Please let me know if this works for you

Comment: During my investigation I try System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore);
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePassword); It seems in this manner the password is seen but now I have java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key. But I import the certificate with keytool from pfx file (pkcs12 chrypto).

Comment: the default keystore might have keys in it with different passwords... and that could be the reason why it is still failing. I won't recommend passing system arguments for this kind of use case as it is in my opinion insecure. Your passwords can easily be extracted from the terminal. However you can easily verify with this tool https://keystore-explorer.org/ if your keystore has key entries which have different password

Comment: keystore-explorer.org is really good! I see in the .keystore that login password is ok and see public key, but if I try to see private key there is the same error "unrecoverable...". So I understand my call try to use the private certificate, but must use the public one!

Comment: I would advise to store trusted certificates in a separate keystore and keypairs (public and private key) in a separate keystore. It would be much more maintainable. I will update my initial answer to give you the context

Comment: Thanks @Hakan54, trying your code (with little customization by me) goes one step on. Now I find this error: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Maybe caused by TLS version? [in my certificate I see TLS Web Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)]

Comment: Is your server or client throwing this error? You probably still need to import the correct certificate to your truststore. The message is saying that the application who is trying to communicate with the server is not trusted

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to do the same using `SSLContextBuilder` which simplifies the trust store loading quite a bit:

```
...
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;


public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File trustStoreFile = new File("/path/to/keystore.p12");
        String trustStorePassword = "truststore-password";

        SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
            .loadTrustMaterial(trustStoreFile, trustStorePassword.toCharArray())
            .build();
        
        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setAddress("https://some-secure-server.com/");

        factory.setBus(new CXFBusFactory().createBus());
        factory.getBus().setExtension((name, address, httpConduit) -> {
            TLSClientParameters tls = new TLSClientParameters();
            tls.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tls);
        }, HTTPConduitConfigurer.class);

        WebClient webClient = factory.createWebClient();
    }
}
```